# Select record from SQL Server like data below

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I  have record like below in SQL Server.

```
 Id    RefId    FromRefId 
  1     RH01    RH00 
  2     RH02    RH01 
  3     RH03    RH01 
  4     RH04    RH03
  5     RH05    RH02 
  6     RH06    RH03 
  7     RH07    RH04 
  8     RH08    RH02 
  9     RH09    RH05
```

And I want get result like below using Id in where condition

```
Where Id=1
RH02
RH03
RH04
RH05
RH06
RH07
RH08
RH09

Where Id=2
RH05
RH08
RH09

Where Id=3
RH04
RH06
RH07

Where Id=4
RH07

Where Id=5
RH09
```

Thanks, please guide me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean FromRefId?

Comment: It's not easy to understand, why you want exactly this result from your Query! Can you explain?

Comment: No, I want to  RefId  
RH02
RH03
RH04
RH05
RH06
RH07
RH08
RH09

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to obtain all the references following the chain of `FromRefId` you need to use a recursive query, which can be achieved in SQL Server using a [recursive common table expression](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/):

```
with Recursive_IDs (Id, RefId, FromRefId) as (
  -- anchor query
  select Id, RefId, FromRefId
  from IDs

  union all

  -- recursive query
  select IDs.Id, IDs.RefID, Recursive_IDs.FromRefId
  from IDs
  inner join Recursive_IDs on Recursive_IDs.RefId=IDs.FromRefId
)
select Recursive_IDs.RefId
from Recursive_IDs
join IDs on Recursive_IDs.FromRefID=IDs.RefID
where IDs.id = [the id you want]
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd1f1/2)

Note that if instead of searching by `Id` you search by `RefId` you can simplify the query a bit:

```
with Recursive_IDs (Id, RefId, FromRefId) as (
  -- anchor query
  select Id, RefId, FromRefId
  from IDs

  union all

  -- recursive query
  select IDs.Id, IDs.RefID, Recursive_IDs.FromRefId
  from IDs
  inner join Recursive_IDs on Recursive_IDs.RefId=IDs.FromRefId
)
select Recursive_IDs.RefId
from Recursive_IDs
where FromRefId = [the RefId you want]
```

Comment: **Thanks** for support. i think i will achieve my requirement by your methodology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below approach. I have written a Table-valued function, "GetChild". It iterates through the records recursively to get all dependencies, and finally get the RefId for all those dependencies.

```
Create table hierarchy (Id int, RefId varchar(10), FromRefId varchar(10))
GO
insert into hierarchy
select   1,'RH01','RH00'  union all
select  2,'RH02','RH01'  union all
select  3,'RH03','RH01'  union all 
select  4,'RH04','RH03'  union all
select  5,'RH05','RH02'  union all 
select  6,'RH06','RH03'  union all 
select  7,'RH07','RH04'  union all 
select  8,'RH08','RH02'  union all 
select  9,'RH09','RH05'

GO
-- Table valued Function
GO
create function GetChild (@Id INT)
RETURNS @temp TABLE (RefId varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN

    declare @tempDependencies table (Id int)
    insert into @tempDependencies SELECT @Id

    WHILE ((Select COUNT(Id) from hierarchy where FromRefId in (select RefId from hierarchy where id in (select Id from @tempDependencies) ) and id not in (select Id from @tempDependencies)) > 0)
      BEGIN
      insert into @tempDependencies 
      Select Id from hierarchy where FromRefId in (select RefId from hierarchy where id in (select Id from @tempDependencies) ) and id not in (select Id from @tempDependencies)
      END

    insert into @temp 
    Select RefId from hierarchy where FromRefId in (select RefId from hierarchy where id in (SELECT Id from @tempDependencies))


    return 
END
GO


-- You may call the functions like this:

select * from GetChild(1)
select * from GetChild(2)
select * from GetChild(3)
```

[SQL Fiddle Code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08de0b/1)

Comment: This runs well in MS-SQL Server

Comment: Thank for support. i have tried both suggestions one of your and another is provided above. i think @alberto-martinez suggestion is more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Should be a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE Id = your_desired_id
```

Why the downgrade? Isn’t that what you were looking for? I don’t think your question is clear. Which Id is being referred here?!

Comment: You shouldn't give an answer, if you don't understand the question! I didn't downvote you, but you should ask in an comment, if you understood the question before answering.

Comment: The downvote was not from him, he doesn't have enough reputation to downvote yet. I think that you were downvoted because the query in your answer doesn't return the result sets given as examples in the question (which I agree is not clear).

Comment: I answered exactly by the question. “Where Id = 1”. The query I stated will give you values by Id but I guess that’s not what he is looking for!